# The session doesn't keep value in flask?

Tags: python, json, string, flask, session

When I login I can store on session but it seems after that session will be empty because I can't go to profile? I also tried from flask_session import Session , app.config.from_object(**name**) but it still have same issue? Also I send request from react.

````
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session
app.secret_key = "tutorialtutorial"
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=data.get("email")).one()
    print(user)
    if not user:
        return "no user"
    else:
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password,data.get("password")):
            # create sesion
            session['user'] = user.firstname
            print(session)
            return "Authorized"
        else:
            return "UnAthorized"
    # if user is not null
    return "Hello login!" 
 @app.route('/profile',methods=['POST'])
def profile():
    print(session)
    print(len(session))
    if "user" in session:
        return "Hello Here is your profile"
    else:
        return "You are not defined" ```
````

Comment: Are you saying that you were able to create the session (“Authorized”) but when you try to POST to /profile later on it doesn't find it (“Hello Here is your profile”)?

Comment: Yes, Also my frontend is React. It seems it creates new session by each request.

Comment: I assume you have `app = Flask(__name__)` somewhere in that file, correct?

Comment: Could you simplify your example and try the following?
```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    session['foo'] = 42
    return 'foo'

@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
    print(session)
    return 'bar'
```

Comment: If I use the code that you gave me on flask full stack will work but if I want to send request from react to flask it doesn't work. It seems by each React request flask create new session.

Comment: You might have to share your front end as well, then.